# Display only username from email in table td element

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

So {{ historydata?.created_by }} is displaying email address. Is there was way to either extract only username from the email address or hide characters after @ and display only username in td element?

```
      <tr *ngFor="let historydata of data?.rows">
        <td class="is-breakable">{{ historydata?.created_by }}</td>
```

Comment: Split by "@" and get the first element of the array?

Answer (score 1):

You can try {{ historydata?.created_by.split('@')[0] }}

I've created a CodeSandbox for you, so you can see it working:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/unruffled-meninsky-59f58p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark